# Maven: exclude version from module jars inside war file

Tags: maven

I have a multi module project. Each module is built into .jar file that takes name corresponding to `${project.artifactId}`. One module is built into .war file. And here is where I run at some issues. WEB-INF folder contains lib folder that contains some result .jars from other modules. And these jars have name like: `project.artifactId+project.version.jar`, when I need just `project.artifactId.jar`.

I tried to configure maven-war-plugin and maven-jar-plugin, but the result is still the same.

Here are some pom.xml files with build results:

**jar module**

```
<groupId>com.mymodule.mysubmodule</groupId>
<artifactId>sub-module</artifactId>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    ...
```

***Result***: sub-module.jar

**war module**

```
<groupId>com.mymodule.warmodule</groupId>
<artifactId>war-module</artifactId>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mymodule.mysubmodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>sub-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<build>
    <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
    ...

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-war</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceExcludes>**</warSourceExcludes>
                        <webXml>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>                        
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

***Result***: /target/war-module.jar, ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/war-module-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,  ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/sub-module-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

`outputFileNameMapping` of war-maven-plugin doesn't suit me because it erases versions of all dependencies, even not from my modules.

How to build .war file with specific jars without versions in WEB-INF/lib folder?